# Where do I enter the Homebrew Scala path /usr/local/opt/scala/idea in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, homebrew

When you install Scala using Homebrew you are told

```
To use with IntelliJ, set the Scala home to:
  /usr/local/opt/scala/idea
```

What exactly does this mean? Is there a global setting in IntelliJ where you enter this path?

Specifically I'm confused because I'm trying to create SBT-backed projects in IntelliJ. In IntelliJ I do New Project -> Scala:SBT and let the IDE create a default project for me. I get a build.sbt that looks like this:

```
name := "HelloScala"

version := "1.0"
```

which looks correct. However, the dependencies are on Scala 2.10.2, while the latest Homebrew-installed Scala on my machine (the one that gets used if I type `scala` at the command line) is 2.11.0. I assume the problem is that I don't have `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea` properly set, but I don't see where in the IntelliJ UI to enter this path information. Specifically, none of the IntelliJ Preferences have a text box for "path to Scala distribution" or some such.

How do I properly set up Homebrew Scala with IntelliJ?

*IntelliJ 13.1.2, OS X 10.9.2*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set scalaVersion in your sbt file or else sbt will use the scala version it was built against.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
```

This will make sbt automagically download the scala 2.11 jars into your ivy cache. Both SBT and IDEA will then use that to compile and run your scala code.

So you wouldn't actually need to install it with homebrew at all unless you want to be able to run the scala repl in a console/manually run scalac etc.

It's only when you do not use the SBT integration you need to point out your scala installation in IDEA.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use the installed version of Scala instead of managed versions by Intelij you do the following:

Open *Project Structure* in Intelij and edit *Dependencies* (use a shortcut on mac:  ⌘+↓).

Then when you want to add a dependency, the finder won't show directories like `/usr` etc. A workaround is to temporarily add this folder to the shortcuts sidebar in Finder, like this:

open a terminal and run: `open  /usr/local/opt/scala/`. This will open a finder and show the `idea` directory. You can drag this to the shortcut sidebar.

Now go back to Intelij and add the directory to Dependencies. I decided to do this under *Global Settings* (in the left pane). Then next I went to *Project Settings > Modules* and removed any existing source of scala and clicked on + to add and selected *"Library.."*. Here you should see the scala version you added under a section called *Global Library*.

Also see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-scala-tests.html

Answer (score 1):

now is 2021 year, for my case:

- `IntelliJ IDEA`: `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Community Edition)`
- OS: `macOS 10.14.6`

answer is: **NO need** set scala location (such as `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea`)

just need:

- in IntelliJ IDEA, open `*.scala` file -> `No Scala SDK in module` -> click `Setup Scala SDK` -> `Add Scala Support` -> for `No Library selected`, clcik `Create`
- selected (here already use brew) installed (by `brew install scala`) `scala SDK`

  - [image]
- IntelliJ will auto recognize it -> after indexing then worked -> can debug scala

  - [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2

If you're managing packages on your Mac using Homebrew, the path to specify on x86 Mac is typically `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea`

[image: Select Scala SDK]

Go to File > Project Structure > Global Libraries > Press the + button > Select Scala SDK > Browse > Specify the path "/usr/local/opt/scala/idea"

[image: Specify path installed by brew]

Select "Apply" and you should be all set!

Comment: For me, the actual directory shows up in the Caveats section of the `brew install scala`: "To use with IntelliJ, set the Scala home to: /opt/homebrew/opt/scala/idea"